# How to deal with the problem that a function parameter name is the same as another function in Python?

Tags: python

Here is an example:

```py
def clean_datetime(x):
    return x

def func(clean_datetime = True):
    if clean_datetime:
        return clean_datetime(1)
        
func(True)
```

This will return an error `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`. Is there a way I don't need to change the function parameter name?

Comment: Change the function name if you don't want to change the parameter name?

Comment: Prefixing the parameter with an underscore would allow you to keep the name without affecting readablity _too_ much, although having two disparate objects with the same or extremely similar names is pretty ugly: `def func(_clean_datetime=True):`

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you could pull the function out of `globals()`, but this is a terrible, terrible thing to do compared to just renaming the function or the parameter.

```
In [53]: def clean_datetime(x):
    ...:     return x
    ...:
    ...: def func(clean_datetime = True):
    ...:     if clean_datetime:
    ...:         return globals()['clean_datetime'](1)
    ...:
    ...: func(True)
Out[53]: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

There is the only one way: you need to change the function name or parameter name.

---

The above one is my older answer(1.5 years), But Yeah you can able to do this my importing the `__main__` module `import __main__ as main`.

Like this.

```
>>> def clean_datetime(x):
...     return x
...
>>> def func(clean_datetime=True):
...     import __main__ as main  # Import the main module
...     if clean_datetime:
...         return main.clean_datetime(1)  # Use the imported function
...
>>> func(True)
1
```

But Yeah by using this you are violating the [`PEP 8`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports).

> *Imports are always put at the top of the file*, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.